# Comparing two values in the same row and change if needed

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Im trying to compare two values in the same record and if 
$minvoorraad > $voorraad , set $voorraad = $minvooraad.

Database(cropped picture): [image]

This is what i have now but it changes all numbers to same

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT Minvoorraad, Voorraad FROM product";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($query === false)
{
  die(mysql_error());

}
else
{

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{

if($row['Minvoorraad'] > $row['Voorraad'])
{
    $minvoorraad = $row['Minvoorraad'];
    $sql = "UPDATE Product SET Voorraad = '$minvoorraad'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}

}
 Header("Location: ../producten.php");


 ?>
```

By the way im a beginner

Comment: sidenote: `die(mysql_error());` that doesn't help, it should be `die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: what are your column types?

Comment: and you also need a `WHERE` clause, otherwise it will update your entire table

Comment: Minvoorraad int(11) Vooraad int(11)

Comment: *"This is what i have now but it changes all numbers to same"* - again... you need a `WHERE` clause. I said that earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will work, unless you need to do query optimization and reduce the locking period

```
UPDATE Product 
SET Voorraad = Minvoorraad
WHERE Minvoorraad > Voorraad
```

Comment: Sometimes it's this easy! Thank you a lot. It happens me a lot where i make things too complicated. I guess that i have a lot to learn!